# Helm upgrade of MongoDB having a Primary-Secondary-Arbiter architecture, is there downtime?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I am thinking of setting up a bitnami mongodb replicaset in K8s, as explained [here](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mongodb#architecture).

However, as a note they mention this while upgrading:

> Note: An update takes your MongoDB replicaset offline if the Arbiter is enabled and the number of MongoDB replicas is two. Helm applies updates to the statefulsets for the MongoDB instance and the Arbiter at the same time so you loose two out of three quorum votes.

I am not sure what does it actually mean "taking the replicaset offline":

1. Is it that the whole mongo service goes offline/down and therefore there is downtime on the service when performing helm upgrades?
2. Is it that, while performing the upgrade, the replicaset will have only one mongodb server working, while both, the other mongo db server and arbiter, are offline and being upgraded?. In this case, it will not imply downtime, just that momentarily, there is just one server available (instead of two), so similar to a standalone setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitnami developer here

> Is it that, while performing the upgrade, the replicaset will have
> only one mongodb server working, while both, the other mongo db server
> and arbiter, are offline and being upgraded?

That will depend on how many replicas you have. If you install the chart with 2 replicas + 1 arbiter, yes it means that. However, if you install the chart with 4 replicas + 1 arbiter, you'll have only 1 replica and the arbiter being restarted simultaneously, having the other 3 replicas up.

> In this case, it will not imply downtime, just that momentarily, there
> is just one server available (instead of two), so similar to a
> standalone setup.

As it's mentioned in the previous response, it does imply a small downtime indeed if the minimum quorum of alive replicas it's not meet.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what Helm is or what it does or why it takes down two nodes at a time, but:

> I this case, it will not imply downtime, just that momentarily, there is just one server available (instead of two), so similar to a standalone setup.

A standalone accepts writes whenever it's up. A replica set node accepts writes only if it is the primary node, and to have a primary node a majority of nodes must be up. Therefore if only one out of three nodes of a replica set is up, there cannot be a primary, and no node will accept writes.

With one out of three nodes available, if this node is data-bearing, you can still issue reads using secondary-allowing read preferences (primary preferred or secondary or secondary preferred), but primary reads won't work and writes won't work.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone tried to upgrade bitnami mongoDB helm chart without downtime, here are some tips I use to *eliminate* it under PSA structure as much as possible, in theory.

The main problem with bitnami chart is that the arbiter and the data node are two separate StatefulSets(mongodb and mongodb-arbiter), so any update using helm will cause both StatefulSets enter the upgrade state and you might only have one data node online for some period of time. And one data node, by definition, replicaset won't be able to elect a new primary and thus unhealthy.

In order to maintain the primary node, only one node in the replicaset could go down each time, so you might simply adding some delay when shutdown data node so that arbiter will be shutdown and backup quicker than any of the data node shutdown. You might simply use the [PreStop Hook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/). However, I did some checks before shutdown --- basically make sure when data node shutdown, every member in the replicaset should be healthy.

Here is an example script you could run in as PreStop hook, and remember to adjust your `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` accordingly to take into account some situations that your instance is not stopping within the given timeframe.

```js
const startTime = Date.now();
const timeLeft = () => Math.round((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000);
let success = 0;
let failedTimes = 0;
const sleepTime = 60; // seconds
// Match graceful shutdown time here
const forceKillTime = 60; // 60 mins
const exitGap = 5; // Leave 5 minutes just in case
const exitTime = forceKillTime * 60 - exitGap * 60;
const CONSECUTIVE_SUCCESS = 5;

while (true) {
  const elapsedTime = (Date.now() - startTime) / 1000;
  if (elapsedTime > exitTime) {
    print(
      `Operation does not finished within time frame: Elapsed(${elapsedTime}) > exit(${exitTime})`
    );
    quit(1);
  }

  const res = rs.status();
  if (res.members) {
    const everyoneIsHealthy = res.members.every((obj) => obj.health === 1);
    if (everyoneIsHealthy) {
      success += 1;
      if (success >= CONSECUTIVE_SUCCESS) {
        print(
          `success count (${success} >= ${CONSECUTIVE_SUCCESS}) larger than threshold, proceeed with shutdown`
        );
        // First, we try to step down
        // Then, we go ahead to shutdown ourselves
        db.adminCommand({
          replSetStepDown: timeLeft() + 60, // add some space just in case
          secondaryCatchUpPeriodSecs: timeLeft() - 60,
          force: false,
        });

        // If step down has timeout, we basically cannot do anything but proceed to force shutdown anyway
        // to ensure the shutdown happened. However the final killoff is done by k8s, shutdown is also for
        // index task to wrap up, etc.
        db.shutdownServer({
          timeoutSec: timeLeft(),
        });
      } else {
        print(
          `success count (${success} < ${CONSECUTIVE_SUCCESS}), keep checking...`
        );
      }
    } else {
      success = 0;
      failedTimes += 1;
      print(`[Failed ${failedTimes}] not everyone is healthy, reset counter `);
    }
  } else {
    success = 0;
    failedTimes += 1;
    print(`[Failed ${failedTimes}] members info not available, retrying...`);
  }

  sleep(sleepTime * 1000);
}
```

To mount the script you could make use of the bitnami chart parameters: `extraVolumeMounts` and `extraVolumes`. Pack your scripts into a separate package such as `default/mongodb-addon`. Here is an example to patch the StatefulSet to make use of the helmfiles config:

```yaml
- name: mongodb
  needs:
    - default/mongodb-addon
  namespace: default
  version: 9.0.1
  chart: bitnami-full-index/mongodb
  strategicMergePatches:
    - apiVersion: apps/v1
      kind: StatefulSet
      metadata:
        name: mongodb
        namespace: default
      spec:
        template:
          spec:
            # If this value changed, changed the shutdown script timer as well
            terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 3600 # 60 minutes
            containers:
              - name: mongodb
                lifecycle:
                  preStop:
                    exec:
                      command:
                      - /bin/bash
                      # Write some wrapper scripts to execute on *local* container instance only, do not connect as replicaset mode!
                      # such as bash -c "mongosh 'mongodb://localhost' $SCRIPT_DIR/shutdown.js"
                      - /scripts/shutdown.sh
```

Still, you could just save these hassle by adding some sleep into hooks and it should probably fine in my opinion. Your replicaset should never lose primary if everything is going well, given that all instances are properly shutdown. Instance shutdown implies stepDown.

---

Another note here is mongoDB Arbiter seems to be not working as expected. For example, if you are upgrading from 4.2 to 4.4, if Arbiter image upgrades to 4.4, it will not take FCV 4.2 thus replset cannot recover to healthy state and block the upgrade in our setup.

Our solution currently is to patch the chart again and pin the arbiter version to 4.2, rolling the data bearing node first and remove the patch when everything is stable.